# SQL query to select highest ID only where field is equal to value

Tags: mysql, sql

Table 'section':

[image]

I am trying to create a query that does the following:

```
SELECT stop 
FROM section 
WHERE the id is the highest and the section is JPS_44-300-A-y10-1-1-1-H.
```

In the table above the result would be 1900HA080909. How can I do this using SQL?

Comment: MAX(ID) ?? probably is what you are looking for ?

Comment: Possible Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column -> check that site for more information

Comment: what DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the `LIMIT` function:

```
SELECT stop 
FROM section 
WHERE section='JPS_44-300-A-y10-1-1-1-H'
ORDER BY ID DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: `TOP` is irrelevant and wrong here, since it is needed for mysql ;)

Comment: @DrCopyPaste I understand he is indeed using mysql. How is it wrong?

Comment: because it wont work in mysql and you did not include information that the first approach wont work in mysql but only in tsql

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
select * From YourTable a
where a.ID=(select MAX(ID) from YourTable b where b.Section=a.Section)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT stop FROM section
INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM section WHERE section = 'JPS_44-300-A-y10-1-1-1-H') AS Tbl
 ON section.ID = Tbl.ID
```

Comment: An inner join seems a bit overkill for the simple query he needs.

Comment: I just wanted to show him that there are more ways in which he can achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

Try like that

```
SELECT a.stop FROM section a WHERE a.id IN (
     SELECT MAX(id) FROM section b
    WHERE b.section = 'JPS_44-300-A-y10-1-1-1-H'
)
```